# Spring: How to decorate some incoming requests with extra logic

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have a rest controller class with many endpoints doing certain operations on books depending on action.

My question is a design question, how do I best get the all action specific business logic **out** from the abstract controller class(handleRequest method)? One of options I considered is GOF Template pattern which can fit here nicely. Problem with that is I dont want to create a different and empty implementation class for each action type. Maybe %80 of the incoming action types have a generic flow. I only want to create an exception for certain action types and add some extra logic to them. Another option is Intercepting Filter pattern, still don't fit well to my situation.

```
mainController extends AbstractController{
   ....

  @PostMapping(value = "/getBooks/")
   public getBooks( @PathVariable ActionType action){
       handleGenericBookRequests(action)
  }

  ....
```

}

```
abstract class AbstractController{

 handleGenericBookRequests(action){
  //do mostly generic stuff
  //do generic stuff
 if (action1){
  //do some action1 specific stuff  using action 1 related services
 }
 if(action2){
  //do some action2 specific stuff  using action 2 related services
 }

 //continue
 ..
 }
}
```

Comment: I would do it using GOF: template method pattern, and in my view there is no harm in creating extra class as far as there is no duplicate code. common part should go to super classes and specific part should go to their specific classes

Answer (score 0):

Your question is relevant and you can come thrugh using enumms,

you can define the behaviour of an action using functional interfaces

```
 enum Action{
        Action_1(param -> "action for 1"), Action_2(param -> "action for 2"), Action_3(param -> "action for 3");
        private final DoSomething doSomething;

        Action(DoSomething action) {
            this.doSomething = action;
        }

        public DoSomething getDoSomething() {
            return doSomething;
        }
    }
    private interface DoSomething{
        public Object doIt(Object param);
    }
    handleGenericBookRequests(action){
        Action.valueOf(action).getDoSomething().doIt(your param)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a strategy to encapsulate the work.
Implement it once for the normal stuff and once for each special situation.

Start by separating your request handling from your business logic.
Here is some code:

```
@RestController
public class KapowController
{
    private final KapowService kapowService;

    public KapowController(final KapowService kapowServiceValue)
    {
        kapowService = kapowServiceValue;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/getBooks/{bookId}/{bookAction}"
    public ResponseEntity<BlamType> performBookAction(
        @PathVariable("bookId") final String bookId,
        @PathVariable("bookAction") final String bookAction)
    {
        final BlamType result;

        // in this case, validate bookid and bookAction in the service.
        result = kapowService.performBookAction(bookId, bookAction);

        return ResultEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(result);
    }
}

@Service
public class KapowService
{
    public BlamType performBookAction(
        final String bookId,
        final String bookAction)
    {
        // do stuff.
    }
}
```

Next, you might use a strategy to do the normal and the special stuff.
Here is some code:

```
public interface BookActionStrategy
{
    BlamType doStuff(BlamType blamType, String bookId, BookAction bookAction);
}

@Component
public class BookActionNormal implements BookActionStrategy
{
    public BlamType doStuff(
        final BlamType blamType,
        final String bookId,
        final BookAction bookAction)
    {
        // do normal stuff.
        // maybe conditionally based on the BookAction.

        // do something meaningful with blamType.
        return blamType;
    }
}

@Component
public class BookActionSpecial implements BookActionStrategy
{
    public BlamType doStuff(
        final BlamType blamType,
        final String bookId,
        final BookAction bookAction)
    {
        // do special stuff based on the BookAction.

        // do something meaningful with blamType.
        return blamType;
    }
}
```

Inject a `List` of the strategy into the service

```
final List<BookActionStrategy> bookActionStrategyList;

KapowService(final List<BookActionStrategy> bookActionStrategyListValue)
```

Finally, call each strategy in the `KapowService.performBookAction` method.